# call "exit" from within shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a simple script (for an embedded system) that mounts an external file from the network and then calls `exit` on the command line (which exits the busybox terminal and boots the system from the newly-mounted root directory). Problem is, when I call `exit` from the shell script it exits the script, not the outer terminal. Any hints as to how to send the `exit` command outside the script?

My code looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount /mnt/root 1.2.3.4:/path/to/external/files -o nolock
exit   # exits the script, not the outside filesystem!
```

Comment: well, your parent shell is(`outer shell`) calling a script which gets executed in a child process, a subshell. No way you can call something which gets executed in parent subshell. But instead of calling the script as `./somescript.sh`, you can call it as `./somescript.sh && exit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exit` does indeed exit the current shell. However, running the script creates a new process, and it is that process that exits, not the shell from which you called the script.

You probably want to simply source the file:

```
$ source myScript.sh
```

Then `myScript.sh` is executed in the current shell, rather than a spawned process, and the `exit` will exit from your current shell (and therefore the terminal itself).

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the scripts exits the outer terminal call it like this:

```
source your_script
```

or just

```
. your_script
```

where the `.` is the same as the `source` command. You can follow [this article](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command) if you need more information.

---

Explanation: `source` will execute the script in the *current* shell and therefore the exit will be interpreted by the current shell - what will close the pseudo(!) terminal window, if the shell was the first shell in tree